# Spring integration payload-expression: SPEL expression with args

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to have a payload-expression in spring integration that does this:

```
#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList(#args[0],#args[1],#args[2])}
```

I can't get the args values to be taken as args. What's the proper what to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The #{...} syntax is for SpEL expressions evaluated once, while the context is initialized.

In this case, you simply need

```
payload-expression="T(java.util.Arrays).asList(#args[0],#args[1],#args[2])"
```